# mysqli stmt prepare not working

Tags: php, mysqli

I have absolutely no idea what is wrong here. The same exact statement works in other sections.

Just trying to make a simple prepared select statement and load it into an array.

mysqli has been acting very strangely, crashing/working for random reasons almost.

```
$id = 1;
$s_user = 1000;

$hold = array();
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,"SELECT article_id, title, summary, body, category_id, tags FROM articles WHERE article_id = ? AND user_id = ?")){

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $id, $s_user);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $article_id, $title, $summary, $body, $category_id, $tags); 

   while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
    $hold[] = array(
        'article_id'    => $article_id,
        'title'         => $title,
        'summary'       => $summary,
        'body'          => $body,
        'category_id'   => $category_id,
        'tags'          => $tags
            );
     }       
}
```

Update: Have tried mysqli_errno and putting else statements on the end if it fails.
mysqli_stmt_bind_result is the problem (should note that this is where the if statement fails). If I take that function out it will work.

I've also tried mysqli_stmt_get_result with no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you check `mysqli_error()`? e.g. `if (mysqli_stmnt_prepare()) { ... } else { die(mysqli_error())`? You have essentially ZERO error handling in there. Never assume success when dealing with external resources (especially databases). Always assume failure and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: The OO method makes more sense in my mind.  Maybe learning it would help you understand what is going on better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is how I would write it, because it's easier to write and debug.  You need [mysqlnd](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) to use this code style, but that should be enabled by default in PHP 5.4 and later.

```
$sql = "SELECT article_id, title, summary, body, category_id, tags FROM articles
    WHERE article_id = ? AND user_id = ?";
if (($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) === false) {
    trigger_error($con->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
if ($stmt->bind_param("ii", $id, $s_user) === false) {
    trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
    trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
if (($result = $stmt->get_result()) === false) {
    trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
$hold = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

See? No binding and no looping needed. The final result is that `$hold` contains an array of associative arrays, like you wanted.

You should always check for **false** return value at least for `prepare()` and `execute()`. *Every time.* And possible other mysqli methods too, nearly all of them return false if there's an error.

### Q: How to use $hold? is it like this $hold['username'] or not?

Re comment from @Phil, yes, we can enable exception reporting, but I don't usually put that option out there because most PHP developers who are struggling with mysqli are probably not ready for working with exceptions. But it is nice to use exceptions because you don't have to write all that repetitive error-checking code.

To activate exceptions:

```
$driver = new mysqli_driver();
$driver->report_mode = MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL;
```

Comment: I've found lately (thanks to [another SO contributor](http://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense)) that using `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)` works best. This makes the *mysqli* classes throw exceptions on error, much like PDO with `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately this one is also breaking for me.(at bind_param) Do I need to switch to how I'm connecting to the database to use this method? Or could it be that I simply have something out of date?

Comment: Bill has this throwing `E_USER_ERROR` if it fails. Please make sure you have `display_errors` turned on (_always in development_!) so you can see what error is issued.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`